# UITableViewCell of mixed xibs and programmatically generated UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to integrate a UITableViewCell generated programmatically from code like so:

```
UITableViewCell *newCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, screenWidth, 150];
```

However the rest of the cells in this table view are generated with xibs that rely on autolayout, and so the original programmer only used the `estimatedHeightForRow` method rather than the `heightForRow`.

My programmatically generated table view cell is all botched (has the default estimated height of 64 rather than the frame's height of 150) unless I implement `heightForRow` whereas the existing cells are botched as soon as I do implement `heightForRow` in addition to `estimatedHeightForRow`. Is there a way around this conundrum?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use UITableViewCell's designated initializer - initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: instead the UIView's initWithFrame:. However, I don't think that is the cause of your problem as I have tested initWithFrame: and it appears to default to default style and no reuse identifier.

You haven't said what you are doing with the cell once you instantiate it. Are you using the default layout or adding your own custom views? The default layout (with just a line of text) appears to work correctly in my testing, with the cells being sized according to the amount of text in the textLabel.

If you are adding custom views you need to ensure that the contentView has vertical constraints that fully define its height. For example, if you have two UILabels vertically aligned then you will need a vertical constraints such as @"V:|-10-[label1][label2]-10-|". If the constraints are not fully defined then contentView will collapse to zero and your views will appear overlapping the next cell.

To give a little more detail, when using self-sizing cells UITableView does not look at the frame of the returned cell but rather calls the cell's systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:. This results in the Auto Layout engine analyzing the cell's constraints to calculate the appropriate layout size. UITableView then sets the cell's frame according to that size and its position in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an if statement in your height for row method and set the heights to their corresponding cell. It would also be easier if I could see code.